Issue with sending images using SignalR in Angular and ASP.NET Core 6
I'm encountering an error while trying to send images using SignalR. For the client-side, I'm using Angular 10, and for the server-side, I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.
Below is the code snippet from my SignalR hub:
public async Task SendImageToAdmin(string user, string receiverConnectionId, byte[]? imageData)
{
    await Clients.Client(receiverConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveImage", user, imageData);
}


In my Angular service, I have the following method:
public async sendImage(user: string, receiverId: string, arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) {
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  return this.connection.invoke("SendImageToAdmin", user, receiverId, uint8Array);
}


And here's the implementation in the component:
async handleImageUpload(event: any) {
  const user = this.username; // Replace with the current user's ID
  const receiverId = this.ReceiverId; // Replace with the recipient's ID
  const imageFile = event.target.files[0];
  await this.uploadImage(user, receiverId, imageFile);
}

async uploadImage(user: string, receiverId: string, imageFile: File) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = async () => {
    const arrayBuffer = reader.result as ArrayBuffer;
    await this.chatService.sendImage(user, receiverId, arrayBuffer);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageFile);
}


And here's the HTML code:
<input type="file" (change)="handleImageUpload($event)" accept="image/*">


However, upon uploading an image, I'm encountering the following error:
Error: Failed to invoke 'SendImageToAdmin' due to an error on the server.

Could you please assist me in finding a solution to this issue?

The amount of data is too big for signalr. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262041/how-to-send-big-data-via-signalr-in-net-client

If file size is an issue, then the connection gets closed and the following error occurs: "Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error." Since I am using .NET Core, I have already added this line: builder.Services.AddSignalR(e => { e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; }); and the size error is gone. However, after that, the mentioned error is occurring.

I think your issue might be related to trying to send an ArrayBuffer / byte[] using signalR.
You could try converting the file to its Base64 representation and sending that over SignalR instead?
E.g. Server side:
public async Task SendImageToAdmin(string user, string receiverConnectionId, string? imageData)
{
    await Clients.Client(receiverConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveImage", user, imageData);
}

E.g. Client side:
My helper method I use to convert a file to base64:
private async toBaseSixtyFour(file: File): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result?.toString() ?? '');
    };
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });
}

Angular component:
async uploadImage(user: string, receiverId: string, imageFile: File) {
  const fileAsBase64 = await this.toBaseSixtyFour(imageFile);
  await this.chatService.sendImage(user, receiverId, fileAsBase64);
}

Chat Service:
public async sendImage(user: string, receiverId: string, imageData: string) {
  return this.connection.invoke("SendImageToAdmin", user, receiverId, imageData);
}

I have not ever tested this, but I think this approach will be fine for smaller images. Other more complex file types, or a larger image, will most definitely prove problematic.
It might be more worthwhile to investigate an alternative approach. Perhaps the following could work:

Client selects image
Image is sent to the server using HTTPS
The server saves the image, and then uses signalR to notify the receiver of the new image
Receiver then knows to fetch the new image using HTTPS

In the above approach, all things file-related can be handled as normal using HTTPS and a controller, and SignalR can be used to keep everything in 'sync'.
